# Netty 4 alternative to LineBasedFrameDecoder

Tags: java, netty

Is there a more efficient way to search for a line delimiter sequence on a `ByteBuf`? In particular I'm looking for a way to find a `\r\n` sequence.

Because I want to search for 2 bytes using `bytebuf.forEachByte(ByteBufProcessor)` won't work.

The easiest way I could find so far is to use a `LineBasedFrameDecoder`. The problem is that some messages I receive can be quite big (in MB range) and just like Norman Maurer mentioned [here](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#18.0) looping through the `ByteBuf` is very inefficient when dealing with messages this big (can take minutes to find the delimiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still search for two bytes:

```
public class CrLfProcessor implements ByteBufProcessor{
  private byte previousByte;

  @Override
  public boolean process(byte value) {
    if(previousByte == '\r'){
      if(value == '\n'){
        return false;
      }
    }

    previousByte = value;
    return true;
  }
}
```

---

Here is a JMH benchmark testing various optimizations:

```
Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class ByteBufProcessorBenchmark {
  private static interface ByteProcessor {
    boolean process(byte value);
  }

  private static final int DATA_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
  private byte[] data;

  @Setup(Level.Trial)
  public void setUp() {
    data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
    Random random = new Random();
    random.nextBytes(data);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void crFirst(Blackhole blackhole) {
    ByteProcessor byteProcessor = new ByteProcessor() {
      private byte previousByte;
      @Override
      public boolean process(byte value) {
        if(previousByte == '\r'){
          if(value == '\n'){
            return false;
          }
        }

        previousByte = value;
        return true;
      }
    };

    doProcess(byteProcessor, blackhole);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void lfFirst(Blackhole blackhole) {
    ByteProcessor byteProcessor = new ByteProcessor() {
      private byte previousByte;
      @Override
      public boolean process(byte value) {
        if (value == '\n') {
          if(previousByte == '\r'){
            return false;
          }
        }

        previousByte = value;
        return true;
      }
    };

    doProcess(byteProcessor, blackhole);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void crFirstUpdateCacheOnDemand(Blackhole blackhole) {
    ByteProcessor byteProcessor = new ByteProcessor() {
      private byte previousByte;
      @Override
      public boolean process(byte value) {
        if(previousByte == '\r'){
          if(value == '\n'){
            return false;
          }
          previousByte = 0;
        }else if(value == '\r'){
          previousByte = value;
        }
        return true;
      }
    };

    doProcess(byteProcessor, blackhole);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void lfFirstUpdateCacheOnDemand(Blackhole blackhole) {
    ByteProcessor byteProcessor = new ByteProcessor() {
      private byte previousByte;
      @Override
      public boolean process(byte value) {
        if (value == '\n') {
          if(previousByte == '\r'){
            return false;
          }
          previousByte = 0;
        }else if(value == '\r'){
          previousByte = value;
        }
        return true;
      }
    };

    doProcess(byteProcessor, blackhole);
  }



@Benchmark
  public void consume(Blackhole blackhole){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      blackhole.consume(data[i]);
    }
  }


  private void doProcess(ByteProcessor byteProcessor, Blackhole blackhole){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      blackhole.consume(byteProcessor.process(data[i]));
    }
  }

}
```

And here a re the results:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:01:21

Benchmark                                             Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.crFirst                     avgt   10  4,211 ± 0,061  ms/op
ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.crFirstUpdateCacheOnDemand  avgt   10  4,285 ± 0,336  ms/op
ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.lfFirst                     avgt   10  4,375 ± 0,289  ms/op
ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.lfFirstUpdateCacheOnDemand  avgt   10  4,129 ± 0,075  ms/op
ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.consume                     avgt   10  3,126 ± 0,152  ms/op
```

As you can see the fastest option is `ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.lfFirstUpdateCacheOnDemand` but the difference with `ByteBufProcessorBenchmark.crFirst` that it does not outweigh the added complexity.

Also what are your performance requirements, because 4ms (including the blackhole which you can see from the results takes 3ms) per MB IMHO is not slow at all; At the end you get 1MB per millisecond which is not bad at all.

Comment: I cannot reuse the processor and it still isn't fast enough. But its better than what I have at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: You can reuse it - just add a method named `reset()` that sets `previousByte` to let's say 0 and call that method before using the processor on another buffer. Also you might want to check if there will be any performance difference (due to cache effects) by swapping the two `if` statements.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the info. Changing this won't have any significant impact right now because I have other bottlenecks to address first. I'll add a note to look into this in the future.